# Execute a server-side function from MongoClient in node.js

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I've created a set of functions on my MongoDB server that I'd like to be able to use from `MongoClient` in my nodejs scripts. [All](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/server-side-javascript/) [of the](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/eval/) [documentation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/store-javascript-function-on-server/) I've read tells me how to do this, but from the shell only it seems.

How it would normally work in the shell:

```
mongo database my.script.js
mongo
> use database
> db.loadServerScripts()
> add("This is a string taken in by the add function I just loaded")
```

This is what I've tried/looked into (mind the CoffeeScript):

```
MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient

MongoClient.connect 'mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/database', (e, db) ->
    console.log db.eval              #Function, but not sure what to call with
    console.log db.runCommand        #undefined
    console.log db.loadServerScripts #undefined
    console.log db.load              #undefined
    console.log db.command           #Function, but not sure what to call with
    console.log db.add               #this is one of my custom functions
```

Hopefully this is possible with MongoClient. It seems as though I could use `eval()` if I can manage to load the script, but that's proving to be the difficult part so far. Alternatively, I suppose I could minify my functions and run those through `eval()`, but I'd prefer not to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `eval` (it looks like you don't need to load any functions first, the load command is only to make the functions available from the shell):

```
db.eval('add("This is a string taken in by the add function I just loaded")', function(err, result) {
  ...
});
```

Or, if you want to be a bit more flexible in passing arguments:

```
db.eval('function(x) { return add(x); }', [ ARG ], function(err, result) { ... });
```

(it seems that you can't just use `'add'` as first argument, you need to wrap it in an anonymous function first, but I might be missing something...)

Comment: This seems to be giving me a lot of `undefined is not a function` when I run it. I'll investigate further and see if I can get it working. Thanks.

Comment: Nevermind. I was making some pretty goofy mistakes, and it messed with me. I noticed in your eval() call you pass a callback, which is not what I was doing. Everything checks out now, thank you.